# Possible to Launch a Screen Flow from a LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I know it's possible to launch a flow [from Aura components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_lc.htm), I'd like to know if this can also be done from a LWC.

Please note that I'm **not** trying to add a LWC into a screen flow - which is an upcoming [feature in Winter '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_solutions.htm).

So is this possible, and if not, are there any workarounds (aside from building the component using Aura)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. As of today its not available. You can keep checking the documentation [Base Components: Aura Vs Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components) to know:

> The table lists usage differences between Aura base components and
>   their Lightning web component counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: Are there any decent workarounds that you could suggest?

Comment: the simplest would be to wrap LWC comp in aura comp, fire custom event from lwc which will be taken care by aura to launch

Comment: By the way, this worked like a charm, thanks

Comment: @MH can you provide an answer with an example of your workaround?

Answer (score 1):

With the Winter '23 release (56), we can now use the `lightning-flow` component.

The lwc's html would use it as:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-flow
        flow-api-name="Survey_customers"
        flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
        onstatuschange={handleStatusChange}
    >
    </lightning-flow>
</template>
```

If youre retooling an existing lwc, you may need to update the api version in the lwc's metadata file to use a feature of a new version:

```xml
<apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
```

Here's some docs I could find:

lightning-flow: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow/documentation

release note: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_lwc_launch_screen_flows.htm&release=240&type=5